# Overlay network aware HAProxy

Tags: docker, overlay, haproxy, consul

I am playing with Docker 1.10 / Compose 1.6.2 and creating an overlay network using Consul as the K/V store. If I scale services I can ping them as expected. Now it comes to load balancing these services.

Given an overlay network using DNS is there an "off-the-shelf" solution using HAProxy that will automatically update its configuration to load balance against instances of the services that are available on the overlay network?

Comment: Docker 1.11 now supports DNS round robin behaviour so it is easy to configure a proxy like nginx to do round-robin load balancing to Docker containers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a solution for just such a scenario. It is called `interlock`. Please refer to this link for more information: https://github.com/ehazlett/interlock

I have tried interlock and it works very well.

Another solution I have heard, but not tried is `traefik`. Link here: https://github.com/containous/traefik

Comment: Thanks for the information. I also found this might work: https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-haproxy